# multiple inputs in a same form gwidgets2

Tags: r, gwidgets

I am trying to put several `ginputs` into a form in `gWidgets2`, or to get the text entered in a `gedit` widget as a list or something to use in the rest of the code,

```
library(gWidgets2)
options(guiToolkit = "tcltk")

prj_name   = ginput("Project name")
user = ginput("User name")
transfer = ginput("Transfer amount")
```

I tried with `gformlayout` but they `ginput` apparently can't be contained in one; and I haven't found how to pass the inputs on the widget to an object (a `list` in this case) in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ginput` is a dialog. The widget you want is `gedit`. This example is from the help page of `gformlayout`

```
 w <- gwindow("gformlayout", visible=FALSE)
     g <- gvbox(container=w)
     
     flyt <- gformlayout(container=g)
     gedit("", label="Name:", container=flyt)
     gedit("", label="Rank:", container=flyt)
     gedit("", label="Serial No.:", container=flyt)
     
     b <- gbutton("Show me", container=g, handler=function(h,...) {
     print(svalue(flyt))
     })
     
     addSpring(g) 
     visible(w) <- TRUE
```